# How to use Angular from server and specific directory?

Tags: angular, angular-cli

I am using angular from server, not in client machine.for example, server ip is 192.168.100.100 or url is http://www.testserver.com and angular is in specific directory

so i tried

```
ng serve --host http://192.168.100.100:4500/angular/my-app
```

OR

```
ng serve --base-href http://www.testserver.com/angular/my-app
```

But not working

It is working from dist directory

```
http://www.testserver.com/angular/my-app/dist/index.html
```

But that required to run **ng build --prod** on every changes :(

Comment: Do you have a webserver such as nginx or IIS or similar set up on that server?

Comment: it is Debian server

Comment: Look into setting up nginx on your debian server

Comment: isn't it possible to run without nginx?

Comment: Do you want to run or server or host it on server ?

Comment: i just want it to  execute basic setup from server to browser

Comment: Then you need something like nginx (or an alternative like apache) to handle the HTTP requests

Comment: but apache is already there. Why can't i use that?

Comment: @BhumiShah please check this https://angular.io/guide/deployment#production-servers

Comment: @BhumiShah If apache is already there, by all means, use that

Comment: I have tried htaccess changes already but getting 404

Comment: https://192.168.100.100/angular/my-app/index.html -> this path i am trying to acces

Comment: If you want to build the app into a specific folder instead of `dist` try using the option `ng build --prod --output-path=/path/to/folder/my-app`

Comment: Output path MUST not be project root directory..giving me this error even not root directory